# Die "Dichter- und Denkerpose" in der deutschen Literatur seit dem 18.Jh

Tags: etymology, history

Ich suche nach Nennungen, Charakterisierungen und Transformationen der **Denkerpose**<sup>1</sup> in literarischen und poetologischen *deutschen* Texten seit dem 18. Jahrhundert.  Wie ist es zu dem Klischee gekommen? Wer hat es geprägt? Wird die Pose eher Denkern/Philosophen zugerechnet oder auch Dichtern?

Natürlich lässt sich die Entwicklung auch in anderen Sprach- und Zeiträumen untersuchen, allerdings halte ich die Betrachtung im Kontext des 18. JH und der Zeit danach im deutschen Sprachraum für besonders interessant. Dies liegt daran, dass Autorschaftsmodelle in dieser Zeit eine starke Wandlung vollziehen und sich Schaffens- und Rezeptionsprozesse vom Kollektiv ins Individuum wandeln (Peter Bürger). Ich suche also nach Beispielen in deutscher Literatur, die die Denkerpose als Alltagsentrückung und Individualisierung manifestieren.

---

<sup>**1)**
Denkerpose: alles was mit</sup>

- Kopf in der Handfläche
- oder Kinn aufgestützt
- und Blick entrückt
- ...

zu tun hat.

Comment: [Zur Illustration.](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Paris_2010_-_Le_Penseur.jpg)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Dazu auch noch interessant: Diese Bronze hieß vormals "Le Poète"

Comment: Älter: http://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichston

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an international phenomenon.

Comment: Im Gegensatz zur Denkerpose bringt eine Dichterpose für mich eher ein Zürücklehnen mit sich. Zum Denken muss man sich konzentrieren (mow. wörtlich: zusammen mittig ausrichten), wärend man sich für's Dichten öffnen muss. #nopseudo

Answer (score 4):

Glaube nicht, dass solche Posen speziell auf deutsche Dichter zu beziehen sind. Siehe Michelangelos Skulptur Lorenzo di Medici oder Dürers Melancholia. Nachdenkliche Gestik ist eine menschliche Körperhaltung, die nicht erst seit dem 18. Jahrhundert beobachtet wurde.

Comment: Natürlich lässt sich die Entwicklung auch in anderen Sprach- und Zeiträumen untersuchen, allerdings halte ich die Betrachtung im Kontext des 18. JH und der Zeit danach im deutschen Sprachraum für besonders interessant. Dies liegt daran, dass Autorschaftsmodelle in dieser Zeit eine starke Wandlung vollziehen und sich Schaffens- und Rezeptionsprozesse vom Kollektiv ins Individuum wandeln (Peter Bürger). Ich suche also nach Beispielen in deutscher Literatur, die die Denkerpose als Alltagsentrückung und Individualisierung manifestieren.

Comment: @MillaWell es wäre gut, wenn du Informationen dieser Sorte in deine Frage einbaust ;) Das macht es deutlich einfacher dir eine Antwort so zu geben, dass du sie gut findest...

Comment: Ich muß Vogel612 recht geben. Auch mir ist unklar, wie man in Texten nach Posen der Nachdenklichkeit suchen kann.

Comment: @rogermue Ich sehe hier keinen Kommentar von Vogel612, in dem er sich in dieser Weise äußert. "sie" und "gut" in "sie gut findest" beziehen sich offenkundig auf "eine Antwort", und "finden" hat dort die Bedeutung "beurteilen", nicht "eine Suche erfolgreich abschließen". - Gibst Du ihm trotzdem recht? ;-)

Comment: @MillaWell Ich habe Deinen Kommentar in die Frage eingearbeitet, um das Risiko zu senken, dass sie als off-topic geschlossen wird.

Comment: Als Bild wäre für diese Thematik Der Wanderer über dem Nebelmeer von Caspar David Friedrich (1818, Romantik) gut geeignet. Vielleicht gibt es dazu auch einen passenden Text, denke da an Novalis.